# while loop counter comparing two lists

Tags: python, list, while-loop, counter

I need some help please. I have two lists below:

```
sentences = ['The green monkey green age the blue egg','How many yellow green monkey"s are in the green forest']
color =['orange', 'green', 'yellow', 'violet', 'blue']

totals = []

for sent in sentences:
  print sent
  for sent in sentences:
      totals.add((sent, sum(sent.count(col) for col in color))
```

My goal is to count how many times an element in color appears in any given element in sentences. So my output will have each sentence element and the count for elements in color that are present. any help with this would be very much appreciated. I'm a beginner and so far enjoying python :)

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far. We're here to help you fix your code and learn what you did wrong, not do your homework for you.

Comment: Haha this isn't home work. i'm just a curious beginner. So far I can get the sentences that are matched. But I'm not sure how to include a counter to increment each sentence. Please see my edit for what I have done so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Counter` is probably the most Pythonic (and shortest) way to do it, but strings also come with a built-in `count` method that you can use:

```
color =['orange', 'green', 'yellow', 'violet', 'blue']
sentences = ['The green monkey age the blue egg', 'How many yellow monkey"s are in the green forest']

for sent in sentences:
  print sent
  for col in color:
    print "", col, sent.count(col)
```

Output:

```
The green monkey age the blue egg
 orange 0
 green 1
 yellow 0
 violet 0
 blue 1
How many yellow monkey"s are in the green forest
 orange 0
 green 1
 yellow 1
 violet 0
 blue 0
```

### Edit:

If you just want the sentence next to the total number of colors in the sentence, replace the last `for` loop with a sum and [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/):

```
for sent in sentences:
  print sent, sum(sent.count(col) for col in color)
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the output i'm looking for. Is there a way to actually get the sentences instead of the colors. and the count in the col to the right. I'm looking for the total count for each sentence You're good!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for in the output. Do you want the sentence printed next to the total number of "color words" in the sentence (e.g. `("green blue stuff", 2)`)?

Comment: exactly nemec!!!!!!!! thank you. so does that become a dictionary structure? I wouldn't be in a list would it? Thank you. Just curious and enjoying this stuff.

Comment: No, I'm not actually storing the count anywhere (just printing it to output). If you wanted to store it in a dictionary, you would want to use `sent` as the key and `sum(sent.count(col) for col in color)` as the value.

And to store it into a list called `totals`, replace the text `print` with `totals.add((` (note two open parentheses) and add `)` to the end of the same line. That will store a tuple containing the sentence and the count into the list.

Comment: Perfect nemec. This is perfect. I'll trim out the results to exclude those that don't have a count as I see there are dupes. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. The reason I brought up a dictionary is because I might want to analyze the result set and the count field will be very helpful. I don't need it to be in a dictionary to do that do I?

Comment: It doesn't have to be in a dict, but if you want to process the data multiple times it might be worth it.

Comment: Ok so the only problem i'm having is with storing. You suggested i add totals.add(() but that is throwing an exception. Please see my edit. Thank you

Comment: Whoops. I've been using too much C#. @bcorso is right, `append` is the correct term.

Comment: But thank you for getting me there. Next i'll like to do some analytics on the counts. I've learnt so much thanks you guys. Thx

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to use [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
color =['orange', 'green', 'yellow', 'violet', 'blue']
sentences = ['The green monkey age the blue egg', 'How many yellow monkey"s are in the green forest']
from collections import Counter

for line in sentences:
    print Counter([word for word in line.split() if word in color])
```

Comment: Oh i see. so that puts it into a dictionary structure. hmm ok let me play around with it and see what I get. I'll bug you again. Thank you Artsiom.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to look up in each sentence for each of the colors:

```
for sentence in sentences:
    count = 0
    for color in colors:
        for word in sentence.split(' '):
            if word == color:
                count + = 1
    print count
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
print [(s, sum(s.count(c) for c in colors)) for s in sentences]
```

### Output

```
[('The green monkey age the blue egg', 2), 
 ('How many yellow monkey"s are in the green forest', 2)]
```

---

If you want to use the code you have listed in your question, there are 3 mistakes:

1. You only need to loop through sentences once.
2. You need to replace add with append.
3. You are missing a parenthesis at the end of your add/append function.

Fixed code below:

```
sentences = ['The green monkey green age the blue egg','How many yellow green monkey"s are in the green forest']
color =['orange', 'green', 'yellow', 'violet', 'blue']

totals = []

for sent in sentences:
    totals.append((sent, sum(sent.count(col) for col in color)))

print totals
```

Comment: Oh I see. Hmm makes sense.Can you please help me troubleshoot the error in the script i wrote please?

Comment: @user3116753 The error is because list does not have an add() method. Try.append().

Comment: you are only appending one value, a tuple = (sentence, count)

Comment: I will figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: @user3116753 okay, I updated the answer with specific mistakes you made.